# lookup and sum contracts in DB2 SQL

Tags: sql, db2

I'm trying to compute the value of the contract amendments in this below table.

[image: Contract_table]

when there is an amendment to an contract the value is updated with the remainder from the last version of the contract + the value added in the amendment.
To illustrate i added the info on how its calculated in the last column.

How would I go about that in SQL for DB2, I'm hitting a wall here.
Thanks

Comment: Instead of cell references to unknown cells, you should put the actual values that are in the calculation.

Comment: Post also the DB2 version and platform in question.

Comment: sorry, it's DB2 9.7, we use datastage to run the jobs

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a self join each calculating running number by *Contract* with `ROW_NUMBER()` . Specifically, have the `LEFT JOIN` filtered to one row number behind the first `FROM` table. From there columns will align for *AmendmentValue* calculation:

```
SELECT sub1.Contract, sub1.Amendment, sub1.Value, sub1.Billed, sub1.Reminder,
       (CASE WHEN sub1.Amendment IS NULL THEN NULL 
        ELSE sub1.Billed - sub2.Remainder END) As AmendmentValue
FROM
     (SELECT t.Contract, t.Amendment, t.Value, t.Billed, t.Remainder, 
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.Contract 
             ORDER BY CASE WHEN t.Amendment IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE t.Amendment END) rn
      FROM TableName t) sub1
LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT t.Contract, t.Amendment, t.Value, t.Billed, t.Remainder, 
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.Contract 
             ORDER BY CASE WHEN t.Amendment IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE t.Amendment END) rn
      FROM TableName t) sub2
ON sub1.Contract = sub2.Contract AND sub1.rn = sub2.rn + 1
```